# Linking between an excel worksheet and an access query with a formula in it

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have an Access database, and it contains a query that has a formula which is written in VBA in it. I have tried to link this query to an access worksheet.

However, when I try to link using Get Data > From Database > From Microsoft Office Database, the Query is not visible.
If I try using Get Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Query, and click on the Query, a popup window appears that says, "Undefined function 'Name of Function' in expression."

Is there any way I can set up excel so it will recognize the function, or link it in any other way?

Comment: Basically, no. You will have to use different approach. Link to table and do calcs in Excel. Why is Excel involved?

Comment: I just wanted to be able to see it in Excel. It isn't that much of an issue to only have it in Access, it just would have been useful in Excel too. Thanks.